# passing file instance as an argument to the celery task raises "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

Tags: python, django, celery

I need to pass file as argument to the celery task, but the passed file somehow got there closed. It happens just in case I'm executing the task asynchronous way. 
Is this an expected behavior?

views:

```
from engine.tasks import s3_upload_handler
def myfunc():
    f = open('/app/uploads/pic.jpg', 'rb')
    s3_file_handler.apply_async(kwargs={"uploaded_file" : f,"file_name" : "test.jpg"})
```

tasks:

```
def s3_upload_handler(uploaded_file,file_name):
    ...
    #some code for uploading to s3
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 437, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/photohosting/engine/tasks.py", line 34, in s3_upload_handler
    key.set_contents_from_file(uploaded_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1217, in set_contents_from_file
    spos = fp.tell()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

flower logs:

```
kwargs  {
         'file_name': 'test.jpg', 
         'uploaded_file': <closed file '<uninitialized file>', 
          mode '<uninitialized file>' at 0x7f6ab9e75e40>
         }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course, the file would get there closed. Asynchronous celery tasks run in a completely separate process (moreover, they can even run on a different machine) and there is no way to pass an open file to it.

You should close the file in the process from where you call the task, and then pass its name and maybe position in file (if you need it) to the task and then reopen it in the task.

Comment: that means there's no way to pass in memory file instance to the asynchronous task, and i should save it before?

Comment: @ValentinKantor if by "save" you mean "close", then yes, you have to close the file instance

Comment: @Spc_555 he's asking if he has to write the in-memory file to disk if he wants to do something with it in a celery task. The answer is yes, you have to save it to disk before passing its filename to your celery task. Closing an in memory file clears it, so he shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this would be to open the file and get a binary blob which you transfer over the wire. Of course if the file is really large then what @Vasily says is better but wont work in case of the worker running on a different m/c (unless your file is on a shared storage).

Comment: Hi, could you please explain how to get a binary blob from the file?